# ZSH Bindkey to Run Command and Hit Enter

Tags: zsh

What I am looking to have a bind key that executes a command for me. In its current state when I hit `Ctrl + f` in the terminal I see the command and I have to hit enter. I was hoping that maybe key bind would do that for me. I currently have

```bsh
bindkey -s ^f "tmux-sessionizer\n"
```

Am I stuck hitting enter myself or is there something I could do?

Comment: The code you posted does run `tmux-sessionizer` if you press Ctrl+F at an empty prompt. What's the problem?

Comment: It just puts the text `tmux-sessionizer`

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted does run `tmux-sessionizer` if you press Ctrl+F at an empty prompt (at least in the default configuration — in practice you may have the very useful `extended_glob` option set, which requires quoting `^`, e.g. `bindkey '^f' 'tmux-sessionizer\n'`). But it typically won't do anything useful, and could do something bad, if you press it at a non-empty prompt. A better way to run an external command would be to not use the shell input for it, but instead to run it directly. For this:

1. Define a [function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Functions) that does what you want.
2. At the end of the function, [tell the line editor](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle) to [redisplay the prompt](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-redisplay).
3. Register the function as a [line editor widget](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-zle).
4. [Bind a key](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey) to the editor widget.

```
function run-tmux-sessionizer { tmux-sessionizer; zle redisplay; }
zle -N run-tmux-sessionizer
bindkey '^f' run-tmux-sessionizer
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)'s `bindkey` command alone. However, if you install my [`zsh-edit` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit), then you can just use this:

```bsh
bind '^F' 'tmux-sessionizer'
```

Comment: Thank you for this (and for the plugin) @marlon-richert, makes things wayyy easier!

Comment: Glad to hear! 